# Context within a jQuery selection

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<p class="myClass">This is a paragraph
<div>div within the paragraph</div>

More text in the paragraph
</p>
```

My jQuery is:

```
var X = $('div','.myClass');
PRINT(X);
PRINT(X.length);
PRINT(X.selector);
```

X.selector is: .myClass div, which is what I expected, but X.length=0.

Q: What am I not understanding about context? It also doesn't work if I change it to

```
var X = $('.myClass div');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably isn't the answer to your question, but you shouldn't (maybe even can't) use a 'div' inside a 'p'. You should try using a 'span' inside a 'p'.

Comment: This may well be the answer - many DOM parsers will auto-close the p.myClass before the div begins, then auto-open a new one after the div closes, so you effectively end up with `<p class="myClass"></p><div></div><p></p>`. Try running your HTML through a validator, and fix those problems first.

Comment: In chrome if you inspect the element you'll see this:  `<p></p><div></div><p></p>` the div becomes a sibling instead of child.  This is definitely the issue.

Comment: I was just typing this answer - if you change the p and div tags around (and the selector to 'p','.classname' it will work.

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to get the amount of found elements, use `.size()` instead of `.length`

Comment: Actually I think `.length` is usually preferred since `.size` just adds extra overhead.

Comment: Ah, did not know that. I assumed it was the issue since the result came out as 0, but seems the problem is indeed the `div` being inside a `p` element. Changing the `p` to `span` does seem to do the trick.

Comment: the .size() really just does a .length and there has been some discussion of removal of it - except it would break some code.